# Using JavaScript for server-side file processing

Tags: javascript

I have translation files on server and they are world-readable (chmod 777). I need to use translation features in some script functions, for example I need to wait for an `XMLHttpRequest` response from server to show a message. However, according to MDN, you use this API to read files stored on the user's computer. But, can I use this API or any other method in JavaScript to read and process server files?

Let's say I have a translation file `en.csv` stored as `/var/www/html/public/en.csv` with the following content:

```
"A":"B"
"C":"D"
"E":"F"
"G":"H"
```

Where the left column is the source language and the right column is the destination language. It is easy in PHP, but I have problem doing it in JavaScript.

I tried the following script and html markup, but it does not work. The translation file is located in current directory on server.

```
<script>
    function translate(fileName) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var content = reader.readAsBinaryString(fileName);
        document.getElementById('testContainer').innerHTML = content.toString();
    }
</script>

<div id="testContainer">
    <script>
        translate('en.csv');      
    </script>  
</div>
```

Comment: [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) is the correct way to access a file on a server from client. [`FileReader()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) is for accessing the files on the client device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the file as `blob` before reading it:

```js
File.load = function (file_url) {
    return fetch(file_url).then(res => res.blob());
};

function translate(fileName) {
  File.load(fileName).then(function (blob) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
      document.getElementById('testContainer').innerHTML = e.target.result;      
    };

    reader.readAsText(blob);
  });  
}

translate('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nguyennhuttan/testonso/master/en.csv');
```

```html
<div id="testContainer"></div>
```

`FileReader` supports `onload` method, we use this method to make sure the file is read successful.

Source:

- [Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)
- [FileReader.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload)

---

**UPDATE:** Using ajax with GET method

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nguyennhuttan/testonso/master/en.csv',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
      document.getElementById('testContainer').innerHTML = data;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="testContainer"></div>
```

Comment: Before using the `fetch` API, check support at [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Comment: Can't we just use a simple GET with Ajax instead of fetch?

Comment: Is that a mixin you're using in the beginning of your code `File.load`?

Comment: @codezombie I've updated the answer using ajax with GET method. In the first example, if you don't want to use `File.load`, you can remove it, just keep to use the `fetch` method. I've defined it because it's easy to read.